# How to filt histories from another repo?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using TortoiseHg as my VCS, here is the question:

I have 2 repos, `Base` and `Feature`

the `Base`'s history is like this:

```
1 Prod 01
0 Create repo
```

suppose I'm cloning the `Base` to `Feature` now, and add some features in the `Feature` repo. It's history should look like this:

```
3 Prod 02
2 Add xxxxx
1 Prod 01
0 Create repo
```

Here comes the question, how could I only pull `Feature`'s rev3 Prod 02 to the `Base` repo?

cause I want my `Base` repo be clean.

I saw `TortoiseHg`'s repo like this, it's history is kind of:

```
161 bump to rev 30
160 bump to rev 29
```

how did they do this?

Best Regards
Sheng Yun

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [transplant extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) for this.  In the example you gave, assuming `Base` and `Feature` are stored in the same folder you'd execute this command:

```
cd /path/to/Base
hg transplant -s ../Feature 3
```